# MongoDB shell: check if update succeeded

Tags: mongodb

Similar to [MongoDB update: how to check if an update succeeds or fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962414/mongodb-update-how-to-check-if-an-update-succeeds-or-fails) but for default mongodb shell. db.collection.update() will execute silently in both cases: when query has found a document and when not. And getLastError is also null after both updates.

How can I find out that something was actually updated without re-querying collection?

I am using MongoDB version `2.0.4` on `Ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: 2.0.4, I am on Ubuntu 12.04 ; I can update if that will help. What part of docs are you referring to? I have been staring at this very page for hour.

Comment: Not finding a document to update isn't an error.  In the 2.2.2 shell you do get a message to the console regarding how many docs were updated.  e.g. `Updated 1 existing record(s) in 0ms`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`db.getLastErrorObj()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getLastErrorObj/) is what you want to call to get the result of the update.  It returns an object that looks like:

```
{
    "updatedExisting" : true,
    "n" : 2,
    "connectionId" : 35,
    "err" : null,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

`n` is the number of updated documents.

Comment: Thanks, suits me just fine.